# How to check if an activity is associated with a metadata tag or not?

Tags: android, bundle, intentfilter, android-package-managers, extra

I've an activity which has a meta data tag associated with it.

```
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="type"
                android:value="a" />
        </activity>
```

At any point of time from my activity I need to know whether my activity is associated with the meta data tag of type 'a' or not. How to achieve this. I tried something like

```
        Intent intent = mCurrentActivity.getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = (intent != null) ? intent.getExtras() : null;
        String value = (bundle != null) ? bundle.getString("type") : null;
```

but this is always returning me null not `a`. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this for getting metadata:

```
ActivityInfo activityInfo = getPackageManager()
    .getActivityInfo(getComponentName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
Bundle bundle = activityInfo.metaData;
String value = bundle.getString("type");
```

Comment: Incredibly awesome ! It worked ! thanks a ton ! :-)